# aws cli command to change default sing in method

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

So by default, awsmobile set username as default sign-in method. I want to change it to email because now multiple accounts with the same email can be created but these settings in my user pool are disabled. Is there a command in aws cli to change this setting?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the sign in methods are locked once you create the user pool. You can only add in custom attributes afterwards.